# R - How to do the rowwise mutate operation?

Tags: r

Here is my sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(month = 1:12,
                  population = rep(1000, 12),
                  rate = runif(12, 0.01, 0.05))
```

I want to create three new variables **case**, **case_cum**, and **population_1**. I want to do a row-wise operation where the current row depends on the value from the prior row. For example, after first month, **case** can be calculated using prior month **population_1** and current month **rate**.

I tried to solve this using for loops as below.

```
dat$case <- NA
dat$case_cum <- NA
dat$population_1 <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  if (dat$month[i] == 1) {
    dat$case[i] <- dat$population[i] * dat$rate[i]
    dat$case_cum[i] <- dat$case[i]
    dat$population_1[i] <- dat$population[i] - dat$case_cum[i]
  }
  else {
    dat$case[i] <- dat$population_1[i-1] * dat$rate[i]
    dat$case_cum[i] <- dat$case[i] + dat$case_cum[i-1]
    dat$population_1[i] <- dat$population[i] - dat$case_cum[i]
  }
}
```

It works but it takes a while to run if data is big and code is lengthy. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could accomplish this using `cumulative rates`:

```
within(dat, 
        {
          population_1 = population *cumprod(1-rate)
          case_cum = population - population_1
          case = diff(c(0, case_cum))
        })
   month population       rate      case  case_cum population_1
1      1       1000 0.02150310 21.503101  21.50310     978.4969
2      2       1000 0.04153221 40.639134  62.14224     937.8578
3      3       1000 0.02635908 24.721065  86.86330     913.1367
4      4       1000 0.04532070 41.383991 128.24729     871.7527
5      5       1000 0.04761869 41.511723 169.75901     830.2410
6      6       1000 0.01182226  9.815325 179.57434     820.4257
7      7       1000 0.03112422 25.535108 205.10945     794.8906
8      8       1000 0.04569676 36.323924 241.43337     758.5666
9      9       1000 0.03205740 24.317674 265.75105     734.2490
10    10       1000 0.02826459 20.753245 286.50429     713.4957
11    11       1000 0.04827333 34.442817 320.94711     679.0529
12    12       1000 0.02813337 19.104044 340.05115     659.9488
```

The idea is to compute the cummulative rates first:

```
  rr <- cumprod(1 - dat$rate)
  pop1 <- dat$population * rr
  case_cum <- dat$population * (1 - rr)
  case <- -diff(c(1,rr)) * dat$population
```

For case, difference either in case_cum or pop1. They both should yield the same results:

Comment: Haven't thought about cumulative rates. Code reads well!

Comment: @MooMooU `within` is a base R. I did not load any packages. Just used base R. if you want you can use `mutate`

Comment: What if I have another variable **dropout** that records number of people who dropped out each month, and I'd like to get population_1 = population - case_cum - dropout? I tried population_1 = (population - dropout) * cumprod(1-rate) but I get slightly different numbe

Comment: @MooMooU consider asking a new question, and this time round, link that question to the solution given here. But explicitly state that the solution does not solve your current new problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Here I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77262124/r-how-to-do-the-rowwise-mutate-operation-updated

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be faster with vectorized operations. We can calculate the decreasing population with `Reduce` and then can use `diff` and `cumsum` to back fill the number of cases. For example

```
init_pop <- dat$population[1]
dat$population_1 <- Reduce(function(pop, rate) {
  pop - pop*rate
}, dat$rate, init=init_pop, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
dat$case <- -diff(c(init_pop, dat$population_1))
dat$case_cum <- cumsum(dat$case)
```

If you have multiple years, you'd want to split the data by year and then apply these transformations.

Comment: Reduce is not a vectorized functions. Its a wraapper of for-loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [`purrr::accumulate()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html):

> accumulate() sequentially applies a 2-argument function to elements of a vector.

We can also use [`dplyr::lag()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/lead-lag.html):

> Find the "previous" (`lag()`) or "next" (`lead()`) values in a vector. Useful for comparing values behind of or ahead of the current values.

We can set the initial `case` value to `population[1]` using the `default` argument, which is equivalent of what you do in the `if (dat$month[i] == 1)` part of your loop. The cumulative sum can be calculated with the base function [`cumsum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat  |>
    mutate(
        population_1 = tail(purrr::accumulate(rate,  ~ .x - .x * .y, .init = population[1]), -1),
        case = lag(population_1, default = population[1]) * rate,
        case_cum = cumsum(case)       
)

#    month population       rate population_1      case  case_cum
# 1      1       1000 0.02150310     978.4969 21.503101  21.50310
# 2      2       1000 0.04153221     937.8578 40.639134  62.14224
# 3      3       1000 0.02635908     913.1367 24.721065  86.86330
# 4      4       1000 0.04532070     871.7527 41.383991 128.24729
# 5      5       1000 0.04761869     830.2410 41.511723 169.75901
# 6      6       1000 0.01182226     820.4257  9.815325 179.57434
# 7      7       1000 0.03112422     794.8906 25.535108 205.10945
# 8      8       1000 0.04569676     758.5666 36.323924 241.43337
# 9      9       1000 0.03205740     734.2490 24.317674 265.75105
# 10    10       1000 0.02826459     713.4957 20.753245 286.50429
# 11    11       1000 0.04827333     679.0529 34.442817 320.94711
# 12    12       1000 0.02813337     659.9488 19.104044 340.05115
```

Thanks to @MrFlick for pointing out that my previous answer was using a column which didn't yet exist and for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77260988/12545041) which uses `Reduce()` that showed a better way to approach this.

Comment: @MrFlick oops! I'll fix it.

Comment: You also might try to use the tidyverse `lag` function. I’m not particular fan of the tidyverse but it’s `lag` function is a definite improvement over the base `lag` function.

Comment: Note that `accumulate` is just a for-loop in R. I mean the for-loop for accumulate is written in R. With the overheads, i doubt it will be faster than OP's code. Op is interested in speed

Comment: @Onyambu thanks I didn't know that - I assumed it would have been written in C.

Comment: Well I wish they did that. But thats not the case with most functions. You can easily call `purrr::accumulate` and you will note that it calls a function `reduce_impl` then if you do ` purrr:::reduce_impl` you will see its for-loop implementation

Comment: Can you help me understand how accumulate function knows .y is rate? First argument of accumulate is .x which is rate.